# Automatic mounting of encrypted partitions on OS X

Tags: macos, partition, encryption, mount

There is a well-documented method of getting Unix to automatically mount a partition on Mac OS X, namely adding something like this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=C92FFDDD-5E09-34ED-A10D-914EA92EA888 /MountPoint hfs auto
```

However if the partition is encrypted, this won't work.  Does anyone know is there a way to get Unix to mount encrypted partitions?

Comment: How would it mount it without the password? Wouldn't auto-mount, if it worked as you say you want it, defeat the purpose of encryption?

Comment: @ganbustein I'm hoping for some mechanism whereby it can access the password from Keychain.  Clearly it does something like this internally itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [Unlock by Justin Ridgewell](https://github.com/jridgewell/Unlock) to mount my FileVault2 (CoreStorage) encrypted HDD that I have replaced my SuperDrive with.

Unlock will loop through your CoreStorage encrypted volumes (sans boot) and ask if you want them unlocked upon booting.  The passphrase for unlocking them will then be stored in the System Keychain so that another user could login and have them automatically mounted even if they don't know the passphrase for the volume.

So it's a boot time unlocking vs a user login unlocking.

Comment: That sounds very promising, I'll try that.  Thanks.

Comment: Another way is to unlock the second FV2 drive through Disk Utility. Then once it’s mounted you can drag that drive into Login Items under System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> <User>. This will only work for a single user however, not system wide and not at boot.

Comment: Clever, but the directory I really want to do this with is `/Users` and that has to be done at boot time.

Comment: I'm happy enough that this works the way I want it.  Thanks again.